# Что такое User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf

Что значит *"Рисование графика функции вынеси в отдельный User Control"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx):

> Предоставляет простой способ создания элемента управления.

По сути User Control - это просто объединение нескольких уже существующих контролов в целостную группу, которую можно переиспользовать как единое целое. Из минусов: к таким контролам не могут применяться стили и шаблоны.

[Создание проекта библиотеки элементов UserControl в WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb514641(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

> **csharper**, wpf?

Я думаю тут можно и просто Windows Forms обойтись. По сути нужно создать блок элементов.
Я думаю в идеале таких:

- Лэйблы
- GroupBox чтобы отделить эжто все от остальной части информации
- Panel/Canvas(Если вы все же решите WPF)
- Кнопка для перерисовки
- Изменение масштаба / задание пользователем размерности координат (Скроллбары и т.д и т.п)